# Creating a function using value_counts in a for loop

Tags: function, loops

I am attempting to create a function that calls on the value_counts function for every variable in the list that I pass through it.  Admittedly, I have no idea what I am doing and have oversimplified "hello world" tutorials as an example.  My sample code is attached.  Thank you for your help.

```
data1.columns = ['Year', 'Rank', 'Company', 'Revenue', 'Profit']

def vc(*args):
    for x in args:
        value_counts()
    return

vc(['Year', 'Rank', 'Company', 'Revenue', 'Profit'])
```

I have also tried

```
def vc(args):
    for x in args:
        value_counts(x)
    return

vc(['Year', 'Rank', 'Company', 'Revenue', 'Profit'])
```

I get an error stating that value_counts is not defined.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? and what you are getting now?

Comment: Also add your `value_counts` function in your question.

Comment: I am trying to create the vc function to run the value_counts function on each variable as opposed to writing multiple lines of code.

Comment: You have specified the vs() function in your question, but where is your value_counts() function

Comment: I'm not sure what you speak of when you reference "the vs() function".  I tried to place the value_counts function within the for loop inside the function that I am creating.  Obviously I did it incorrectly which is why I need assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing `x` to `value_counts`.

```
for x in args:
        value_counts()
```

should be

```
for x in args:
        value_counts(x)
```

Also, `vc` takes `*args` param, which means you don't need to give it a list. You can call with `vc('Year', 'Rank', 'Company', 'Revenue', 'Profit')`, and when you reference `args` inside `vc` you will get a list. You can call `vc` with a list like you are doing now, but you would change the `def vc(*args)` definition to `vc(args)` so that everything matches up.

Does this help?

Comment: It says that value _counts is not defined as written.  If I try t write it as a normal function, I do not know how to define the value within the for loop.

Comment: Please give us a full python script that includes both functions and we can help you.